# Connection is reset. How to emulate?

Tags: windows, networking, language-agnostic

It seems our software has problems with handling reset connections. How I can emulate connection reset to debug this case?

Comment: Normally, you would have the remote end send an RST packet, but maybe your local network subsystem can do the trick. Did you try yanking out your network cable during a transaction?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, I tried it, but it gives different types of error. Not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For manual testing, check out [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437). This tool allows you to right click any TCP connection and close it; the end result should be the same as if the connection is reset by (say) your not-so-ethical ISP trying to interfere with your traffic.

Comment: It seems this is not the same as connection reset.

Comment: @user626528, could you expand on that comment a little? Back when I used TCPView (~5-10 years ago) it was pretty much the same. How is it different? I think the same messages would go up the stack to the application layer - if not the same, then pretty close.

Comment: it makes "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" error. It's not the same.

Comment: @user626528, don't you think it's similar enough that you could use it to test? If not, your only option is to launch a [TCP reset attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack) against yourself.

Comment: unfortunately not enough. It seems .NET treats "reset" connections differently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool at http://TMUrgent.com/Tools.aspx that allows you to mess up your wan connection and even drop random packets. Look for TMNetSim

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by disabling/enabling the NIC. With [netsh](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm) you can write some bat.